# Radius of curvature at a point in spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, definition, curvature

This is the first time I ask a question here, so apologies in advance if I mess anything up.

I'm reading [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4311) by Eric Poisson and Igor Vlasov. I'm going through it and trying to make some of their points more mathematically precise.
Here is a summary of the points that are relevant to my question: Suppose we have some matter distribution in a spacetime. They call this, the external spacetime. Some distance away from this matter distribution, we then place a (Schwarzschild) black hole. This black hole will be tidally deformed by the matter distribution mentioned above. They go on the define the quantity $\mathcal{R}$ as the [radius of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature) of the external spacetime evaluated at the position of the black hole.

My question is simply, how is $\mathcal{R}$ actually defined, mathematically? In particular, if $(\mathscr{M},g)$ is a Lorentzian manifold with a non-zero Riemann tensor and if $p\in \mathscr{M}$ is an arbitrary point on the manifold, then how do we define the radius of curvature at $p$?

Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The radius of curvature $r(x)$ at a point $x$ is given by $r(x)^2 = \frac{D(D-1)}{R(x)}$ where $R(x)$ is the Ricci scalar at that point.

Comment: Related question: [In what way is the Riemann curvature tensor related to 'radius of curvature'?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54101/in-what-way-is-the-riemann-curvature-tensor-related-to-radius-of-curvature)

Comment: @Prahar Thank you for you answer. The definition you mention, implies that the radius of curvature is undefined at any point where the Ricci scalar is zero. Furthermore, the Ricci scalar is zero if the Ricci tensor is zero. And finally, the Ricci tensor is zero in any region outside of the matter distribution. So the radius of curvature as is used in the article, would then seem to be undefined, since they want to evaluate it outside of the matter distribution. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tobias Ricci scalar $=0$ just means radius of curvature $=\infty$, i.e. flat spacetime.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I see, thank you. In the article, they go on to impose certain constraints of the form $M\ll \mathcal{R}$, which I suppose are then just trivially satisfied for finite $M$.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch that’s obviously an incorrect conclusion. Schwarzschild has zero Ricci tensor, hence zero Ricci scalar, but it is not flat; the Riemann tensor is non-zero.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Right, of course. Thank you for pointing that out. And in fact, I'm considering exactly the case where the "background spacetime" consists of a Schwarzschild black hole. I can't seem to make sense of an infinite radius of curvature in this case. Unless of course we consider an asymptotic limit, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @Prahar Does the definition you provided have any underlying assumptions or is it completely general for a D-dimensional manifold?

Comment: @Tobias - It's a definition. It doesn't need assumptions. For some specialized purposes, one might want a different definition. Although, as far as I know, this is a pretty widely accepted definition.

Comment: @Prahar Ok, thank you. 
Perhaps I'm using the word "assumptions" incorrectly. Here is what I meant: In my question, I said "if $(\mathscr{M},g)$ is a Lorenztian manifold...". I would call this an assumption underlying the subsequent definition of the radius of curvature. Strictly speaking, you can then not use this definition to find the radius of curvature at a point for a general Pseudo-Riemannian manifold, since the definition only applies to Lorentzian manifolds. (continued below).

Comment: Obviously, the definition you gave applies equally well to any Pseudo-Riemannian manifold, but one would then have to explicitly state this. However, maybe there are more subtle "assumptions" behind the definition you gave.

Comment: The concept of radius of curvature makes less sense in pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. Perhaps the question you should start with is - what do you need this concept for? We can decide on the best possible definition for your use-case.

Comment: I need it to establish a length scale as follows: I have a (supermassive) Schwarzschild black hole. Then, some "distance" away, I have a smaller black hole, which is tidally deformed by the supermassive black hole. It is this "distance" that I need to be more explicit about. $\mathcal{R}$ should be the radius of curvature due to the supermassive black hole evaluated at the position of the smaller black hole. In the article, this is used to impose the condition $M\ll\mathcal{R}$ where $M$ is the mass of the supermassive black hole. This ensures a weak tidal interaction.